# Replacing a for loop that iterates over an array with the functional programming equivalent

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

How would I accomplish the same thing in a functional paradigm?

```
Player.prototype.d2 = function(ratingList, rdList) {
    var tempSum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < ratingList.length; i++) {
        var tempE = this.e(ratingList[i], rdList[i]);
        tempSum += Math.pow(this.g(rdList[i]), 2) * tempE * (1 - tempE);
    }
    return 1 / Math.pow(q, 2) * tempSum;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this will work for you.

```
Array.prototype.zip = function(other) {
    if (!Array.prototype.isPrototypeOf(other)) {
            throw new TypeError('Expecting an array dummy!');
    }
    if (this.length !== other.length) {
            throw new Error('Must be the same length!');
    }
    var r = [];
    for (var i = 0, length = this.length; i < length; i++) {
        r.push([this[i], other[i]]);    
    }
    return r;
};

Player.prototype.d2 = function (ratingList, rdList) {
    var self = this;
    return 1 / Math.pow(q, 2) *
        ratingList
        .zip(rdList)
        .map(function (elem) {
            var tempE = self.e(elem[0], elem[1]);
            return Math.pow(self.g(elem[1]), 2) * tempE * (1 - tempE);
        })
        .reduce(function (acc, value) {
            return acc + value;
        });
};
```

Comment: Do you actually need `var self = this`? I haven't had to use that anywhere else so far.

Comment: @Austin - Yes you do need it. Try removing it and see what happens.

Comment: I'm guessing it's because inside the `map` function, `this` would refer to uh... Array.prototype?

Comment: @Austin - I believe that it will normally be the global object.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: interesting approach with zip, to make tuples :-)

Comment: You would only need to do "var self = this" if you don't use Arrow functions. Otherwise you could always use scoped references like " return Math.pow( Player.g(elem[1]), 2) * tempE * (1 - tempE);"

Answer (score 1):

I think this is essentially what you're looking for, if I'm not mistaken:

```
Player.prototype.d2 = function(ratingList, rdList) {
    return  Math.pow(q, -2) * ( 
        ratingList.reduce( ( sum, val, idx ) => {
            let tempE = this.e( val, rdList[idx] );
            return sum + Math.pow( this.g(rdList[idx]), 2 ) * tempE * ( 1 - tempE ); 
        }, 0)
    );
};
```

We start out with an anonymous function for `d2`, whose body is simply a return of the entire functional expression, which uses the `Array.prototype.reduce` function to compose a sum.

I've chosen to use ES6 so I can maintain scope `this` throughout my entire function.

[Reduce explained on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and you should checkout [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

One thing to note: a `for` loop is more performant than functional equivalents.

Comment: Do you realize this question is almost six years old?

Comment: lol, i do now..... it's been a long day.

Comment: Actually, I like this because the accepted answer is a code-only answer, which we consider low-quality here.  It only gets a pass because it's old and accepted.

Comment: @r10y It's actually `1 / Math.pow(q, 2) …`, which could be written as `Math.pow(q, -2) …`. Also a little detail – you're missing a semicolon after `return`.

Comment: cool, updated my answer to reflect your feedback. thanks.